# How do you use nth-child(odd) on table rows but you want some rows to be exempted from the css rule?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My HTML looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr class='trclass'><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr class='trclass'><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>not</td></tr>
  <tr class='trclass'><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr class='trclass'><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr class='trclass'><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr class='trclass'><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr class='trclass'><td>7</td></tr>
</table>
```

and my css is like this:

```
table tr.trclass:nth-child(odd){color:red}
```

This is the link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JKmBK/

I want to do a different style to odd rows on tr that has a class 'trclass', can this be done?

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you want?

Comment: So amongst the rows with that class you want every second one (starting with the first) to be red? I.e., you want to colour the ones containing odd numbers in their td, nothing to do with the row index relative to all the rows in the table? It'd be simple enough with JavaScript, but I take it you want to use CSS only and not change the html to apply an extra class to the rows in question?

Comment: I think he wants 4 to be red.

Comment: The fiddle would be much more useful if it had some comments explaining which rows were to be styled which way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/stevemarvell/JKmBK/4/

It can be done with jquery:

```
$('.trclass:odd').css('color','red');
```

More likely solution would be to add a css class.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, and it depends on whether you want this to be a repeating change or one-off. Let's look at both.

Firstly, if you just want to change a few odd rows with no specific pattern, it would be much simpler to simply add an exception class. Additionally, :nth-child is rather expensive computationally, and so should be avoided unless necessary.

```
table tr.trclass.exempt {
    color: blue;
}
```

See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JKmBK/1/).

Secondly, if you want make this a repeating change, say on every 9th  make the color: blue, you can take advantage of normalized CSS :nth-child syntax, plus CSS's cascading nature to override the (odd) selector.

```
table tr.trclass:nth-child(odd){color:red}

table tr.trclass:nth-child(9n + 9) {
    color: blue;
}
```

See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JKmBK/2/).

I hope this helps! Let me know if I missed your intention.

Answer (score 1):

CSS doesn't know about the semantics of your content, so "odd" means "odd child index by DOM order". If you can, just add an `odd` class to the rows containing odd numbers, and avoid a headache. If you can't do that directly in the HTML, use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this class:

```
table tr.trclass:nth-child(odd){color:red;}
```

Then simply make your exception class be more specific than that:

```
table tr.trclass.exceptionClass:nth-child(odd){color:inherit;}
```

and it will automatically override the less specific style.

But please note that nth-child is [NOT support in IE8](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)...that is a couple versions back, but is still used quite a bit.  Depends on your user base.